# I need a strongloop example wrote in javascript without angular

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, offline, strongloop

I want to have a strongloop example only using javascript without angular.
There's no complete working example without angular for now.
I want to simply include the browser.bundle.js in my index.html, then sync data from/to server side. In fact, I'm trying to replace pouchdb in my program since the couchdb seems not success in open source community.

I can't follow up this document correctly:
[Running Loopback in the browser](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Running+LoopBack+in+the+browser)

1. create browser-app.js with the content from [Running Loopback in the browser](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Running+LoopBack+in+the+browser)
2. copy past the content to browser-app.js
3. npm install loopback loopback-boot
4. browserify browser-app.js -o app.bundle.js Then I got error: Error: Cannot find module 'loopback-boot#instructions' from '/Users/simba/Projects/traveller-app/client/node_modules/loopback-boot'

Comment: What specifically do you need an example for?  As I understand it, StrongLoop is a REST API framework for Node.JS.  Do you need examples of how to get something to work in StrongLoop?  Do you need examples of how to use JavaScript to interact with a RESTful API...?

Comment: Yes, I need write a client in phonegap. I want to simply include the browser.bundle.js in my index.html, then sync data from/to server side. In fact, I'm trying to replace pouchdb/couchdb in my program since the couchdb seems not success in open source community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few steps for this but its pretty simple.

1. Bootstrap your application via `slc loopback`.
2. Delete `server/boot/root.js`.
3. Uncomment two lines in `server/server.js`, it should look like:

   ```
   ...
   // -- Mount static files here--
   // All static middleware should be registered at the end, as all requests
   // passing the static middleware are hitting the file system
   // Example:
   var path = require('path'); //this line is now uncommented
   app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client'))); //this line is now uncommented
   ...
   ```
4. Create `index.html` in the `client` dir (ie. `client/index.html`) with your contents.

That should get you a basic set up with just a basic front-end working. Let me know if you have any more issues.

Comment: Thanks, then I know how to host index.html for now.

Comment: Still, I can't follow up this document. http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Running+LoopBack+in+the+browser
1. create browser-app.js with the content from strongloop
2. copy past the content for browser-app.js
3. npm install loopback loopback-boot
4. browserify browser-app.js -o app.bundle.js
Then I got error:
Error: Cannot find module 'loopback-boot#instructions' from '/Users/simba/Projects/traveller-app/client/node_modules/loopback-boot'

Comment: Take a look at this example, https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-full-stack/blob/c06a292ef95060f20339b18afab4467f36435997/client/lbclient/build.js